# subset a list that does not contain strings in other list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```
words = ['apple','cider','plant']

dt = ['this is apples juice','berry cider tastes great','plants are good for you','great job with that']
```

I want to subset `dt` so that it returns the string that does not contain any of the string in words list.

the result would be: `'great job with that'`

I tried using for loop -- it would work for each of the word in `words`, but won't give me the final result.

```
for w in words:
    for d in dt:
        if w not in d:
            print(d)

berry cider tastes great
plants are good for you
great job with that
this is apples juice
plants are good for you
great job with that
this is apples juice
berry cider tastes great
great job with that
```

Comment: can you show what you have already tried and the results it gave you?

Comment: @Skaperen I just did.

Answer (score 1):

For each string, check that each word is not in string:

```
words = ['apple','cider','plant']

dt = [
    'this is apples juice',
    'berry cider tastes great',
    'plants are good for you',
    'great job with that'
]

for d in dt:
    found = False
    for w in words:
        if w in d:
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print(d)
```

Using the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function helps minimize things but sacrifices readability a bit:

```
for d in dt:
    if not any(True for w in words if w in d):
        print(d)
```

And, if you really want to throw readability in the recycling bin:

```
[print(d) for d in dt if not any(True for w in words if w in d)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, Hope this will help:

```
from itertools import repeat

dt = [
    'this is apples juice',
    'berry cider tastes great',
    'plants are good for you',
    'great job with that'
]
words=['apples','cider','plants']

def checkWords(sent, words):
  tokenized = sent.split(" ")
  for wrd in words:
    if wrd in tokenized:
      return True



def checkNone(sent,data):
  if data == None:
    return sent

data = list(map(checkWords,dt,repeat(words)))
newdt = list(filter(None, list(map(checkNone,dt,data))))

print(newdt)
```